Classification of an endomorphism ring of an elliptic curve over a finite field restricted to p-torsion points
Suppose p is a prime number, and not equal to c. c is the characteristic of a finite field. And an elliptic curve is defined over the finite field. Since an endomorphism of the elliptic curve restricted to p-torsion points (excluding zero map) is an automorphism of E[p] (because determinant of a restricted endomorphism as a matrix algebra over $Z/pZ$ is equal to determinant of a non-restricted endomorphism modulo p, so it is invertible).
In view of the endomorphism ring restricted to p-torsion points as a matrix algebra over $Z/pZ$, and considering its multiplicative group:

If it is an ordinay elliptic curve, the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to a maximum split cartan subgroup of a GL(2,p) (when p splits). So in this case there are two one-dimensional eigensubspaces of a frobenius endomorphism.

Or the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to a maximum borel subgroup of a GL(2,p) (when p ramifies). So there is only one one-dimensional eigensubspace of a frobenius endomorphism.

Or the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $Z/pZ$ (when p divides the conductor). So it is an embedding degree one ordinary elliptic curve.

If the j-invariant of a supersingular elliptic curve is defined on a finite field of order c squared, and not on a finite filed of order c, and c is bigger than 12, then the endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $Z/pZ$. So it is an embedding degree one supersingular elliptic curve.

Now, I claim the endomorphism ring (over algebraic closure) of a supersingular elliptic curve over a finite field of order $c^2$ is isomorphic to a normalizer of a non-split Cartan subgroup of GL(2,p), and equivalent to a split-quaternion algebra, that is, a two-dimensional matrix ring M2 over $Z/pZ$. If the j-invariant is not equal to 0 or 1728, then $c^2$ power Frobenius endomorphism is -c, or +c (+c only happened when in a degree two twist). If the j-invariant is equal to 0 or 1728, then $c^2$ power Frobenius endomorphism is -c. Therefore a $c^2$ power Frobenius endomorphism is always a identity matrix of GL(2,p), and contained in every conjugate of the non-split Cartan subgroup of GL(2,p). End of the proof. The meaning in cryptography: there is always a distorsion map on every (the number is p+1) proper subgroups of E[p] (a non-stabilizer endomorphism over algebraic closure of a proper subgroup of E[p]).


My thought process is that since we can lift an elliptic curve over a finite field to an elliptic curve (E) over a number field with complex multiplication (cm) given by an order (O) whose index is f (called the conductor) in a ring of integers, and since by cm theory, E[$p$] is isomorphic to O/($p$) (when p does not divide the conductor) as an O-module, wherein $p$ is a prime ideal above a prime number p, and E[$p$] is a $p$-torsion group, and the endomorphism group of E restricted to $p$-torsion points as an automorphism group acts O-linearly on E[$p$].

Hint: Think about the splitting behaviour of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}$ and think about the regular representation of \mathcal{O}^*$

@Jimmy a small point: Contrary to your second sentence, an endomorphism restricted to $p$-torsion is NOT in general an automorphism, e.g., multiplication by $p$.  Also, you might have better luck getting an answer if you edited and formatted your question a bit better - as it is, it's a bit of an effort to read. Best wishes -

Thank you for helping me out. Maybe it is not conventional, from my definition, an endomorphism is a surjective isogeny to itself. Therefore a multiplication by p map (a zero map) is not an endomorphism.
